# React App running on Node/Express not rendering after transpile with Webpack.

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

I am trying to serve my React app on top of Node/Express after transpiling with Webpack. I've used create-react-app, but want learn to build from scratch so am new to using Node/Express/Webpack. After going through various tutorials, I am stuck trying to render React elements after transpiling with Webpack (Only HTML is being served).

I also run the following commands to create my bundle.js file and navigate to localhost:3000

-npm run webpack

-node server.js

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <h1>This is from the HTML file</h1>
    <script scr="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My webpack.config.js is currently...

```
var webpack = require('webpack')
var path = require('path') 

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: { 
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: { 
        presets: ['react', 'es2015']
      }
    }]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
  ]
}
```

My server.js file is as follows...

```
var express = require('express')
var path = require('path')
var fs = require('fs')

var app = express()

var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.set('view engine', 'html')

app.engine('html', function(path, options, callbacks) {
  fs.readFile(path, 'utf-B', callback)
})

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), 'index.html')
})

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500)
})

app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log('Server running on localhost:' + PORT)
})
```

And my App.js only contains the follow React elements:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>This is the main App</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Also, my package.json

```
{
  "name": "poke-mean",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:./src node server",
    "dev": "npm start & webpack-dev-server --progress --colors",
    "webpack": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Your index.html has `scr` for the script... you've got a typo, it should be `src`.

Comment: That did it! Thanks!